# Adding attributes for faceting with Algolia C#

Tags: c#, algolia

I have an attribute that I'd like to add for faceting: `ApprovalFL`. When I add the facet in the Algolia dashboard, it works fine until I have to reindex which ends up deleting my facets in the dashboard for some reason. I was thinking, maybe adding the attribute in my code would resolve that. I found the documentation about this step here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/

Here's the C# example they provide:

```
index.SetSettings(
  JObject.Parse(@"{""attributesForFaceting"":[""author"",""filterOnly(category)"",""searchable(publisher)""]}")
);
```

If I understand correctly, this code needs to go in my backend reindexing code (found in my `AdminController.cs`):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ReIndexData()
{
    var algoliaArtistModels = Tools.BuildAlgoliaArtistModels(EntityDataAccess.GetAllAccountInfoes());
    var algoliaUnaffiliatedArtistModels = Tools.BuildAlgoliaArtistModels(EntityDataAccess.GetAllUnaffiliatedAccountInfo());
    var algoliaSongModels = Tools.BuildAlgoliaSongModels(EntityDataAccess.GetAllAcceptedSongs());
    var artistIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("ArtistIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<ArtistAlgoliaModel>;
    var unaffiliatedArtistIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("UnaffiliatedArtist") as IndexHelper<ArtistAlgoliaModel>;
    var songIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("SongIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<SongAlgoliaModel>;
    await artistIndexHelper.OverwriteIndexAsync(algoliaArtistModels);
    await unaffiliatedArtistIndexHelper.OverwriteIndexAsync(algoliaUnaffiliatedArtistModels);
    await songIndexHelper.OverwriteIndexAsync(algoliaSongModels);
    return View("AlgoliaReIndexData");
}
```

However, I don't think I put `index.setSettings` in this block of code, what is the best way to set this attribute for faceting in my backend code? The `ApprovalFL` attribute is stored in my Song indices.

Possibly it should go somewhere here in my `Tools.cs`?

```
public static SongAlgoliaModel BuildAlgoliaSongModel(Song song)
        {
            var model = new SongAlgoliaModel();
            var album = EntityDataAccess.GetAlbumByID(song.AlbumID);
            model.AccountImageURL = album.AccountInfo.ImageURL;
            model.AccountInfoID = album.AccountInfoID;
            model.AccountType = album.AccountInfo.CreatorFL == true ? "Creator" : "Artist";
            model.AlbumID = song.AlbumID;
            model.AlbumName = album.AlbumName;
            model.ApprovalFL = song.ApprovalFL;
            model.Artist = album.AccountInfo.DisplayName;
            model.BPM = song.BPM;
            model.Duration = song.Duration;
            model.FeaturedArtist = song.Artist;
            model.FreeFL = album.FreeFL;
            model.ImageURL = album.ImageURL;
            model.iTunesURL = album.iTunesURL;
            model.LabelName = album.LabelName;
            model.LicenseFL = album.LicenseFL;
            model.SongID = song.SongID;
            model.Title = song.Title;
            model.UploadDate = song.UploadDate;
            model.URL = song.URL;
            model.UserID = album.AccountInfo.UserID;

            return model;
        }
        public static List<SongAlgoliaModel> BuildAlgoliaSongModels(AccountInfo accountInfo)
        {
            var list = new List<SongAlgoliaModel>();
            var songs = EntityDataAccess.GetSongsByUserID(accountInfo.UserID).Where(x => x.ApprovalFL == true).ToList();
            foreach(var item in songs)
            {
                var model = new SongAlgoliaModel();
                model.AccountImageURL = item.Album.AccountInfo.ImageURL;
                model.AccountInfoID = item.Album.AccountInfoID;
                model.AccountType = item.Album.AccountInfo.CreatorFL == true ? "Creator" : "Artist";
                model.AlbumID = item.AlbumID;
                model.AlbumName = item.Album.AlbumName;
                model.ApprovalFL = item.ApprovalFL;
                model.Artist = item.Album.AccountInfo.DisplayName;
                model.BPM = item.BPM;
                model.Duration = item.Duration;
                model.FeaturedArtist = item.Artist;
                model.FreeFL = item.Album.FreeFL;
                model.ImageURL = item.Album.ImageURL;
                model.iTunesURL = item.Album.iTunesURL;
                model.LabelName = item.Album.LabelName;
                model.LicenseFL = item.Album.LicenseFL;
                model.SongID = item.SongID;
                model.Title = item.Title;
                model.UploadDate = item.UploadDate;
                model.URL = item.URL;
                model.UserID = item.Album.AccountInfo.UserID;
                list.Add(model);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK for those using C# .NET it's as simple as adding it to your `Global.asax.cs` for example for me:

```
var songIndexHelper = new IndexHelper<SongAlgoliaModel>(algoliaClient, "Song", "SongID");
songIndexHelper.SetSettings(JObject.Parse(@"{""attributesForFaceting"":[""ApprovalFL""]}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to re-index by the way? Best practice is to set up your index only initially.

Comment: Hey Daniel, this is because new songs are being added by users all the time and I would like for them to be searchable when they go live. Does that make sense? Is there a better way to update search results?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can either integrate Algolia with your song addition module or have a background job that regularly checks for new songs and process it to index. Now, by processing to index, you can push the data with their API, refer to https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/getting-started/quick-start-with-the-api-client/csharp/#push-data. You never need to re-create your index whenever a new song is added, that's inefficient.